# Checking linear combinations of $2 \times 2$ matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

What method would I use to verify that this matrix:
$
\begin{bmatrix}
6 & -8 \\
-1 & -8 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$

is a linear combination of these three matrices

$A = \begin{bmatrix}
4 & 0 \\
-2 & -2 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$

$
B = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & -1 \\
2 & 3 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$

$
C = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 2 \\
1 & 4 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$

Would I just turn these matrices into four element column vectors and do Gaussian elimination? or is there a more appropriate method for this?

Comment: It is **exactly** the same problem as showing that the vector $[6,-8,-1,-8]$ is a linear combination of the vectors $[4,0,-2,-2]$, $[1,-1,2,3]$, $[0,2,1,4]$.  So yes, Gaussian elimination is what you want.

Comment: Thanks @RobertIsrael. I know it was an easy one for you, almost a Dorothy Dixer, not sure if you want to post this as an answer so I can close the question?

Answer (score 0):

It is exactly the same problem as showing that the vector $[6,−8,−1,−8]$ is a linear combination of the vectors $[4,0,−2,−2]$, $[1,−1,2,3]$, $[0,2,1,4]$. So yes, Gaussian elimination is what you want.